# cron launching but not executing script

Tags: cron

I setup a crontab with `crontab -e` and checked it was saved with `crontab -l`:

```
*/10 6-8 * 1-11 1 /home/asarluhi/Documents/Scripts/monday.sh
```

The content of `monday.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

ruby ~/Documents/Scripts/monday_task.rb >> ~/Documents/Scripts/monday
```

`monday_task.rb` is a ruby script which web scrapes some data, too long to report it here, but there are no mistakes in it. `monday` is a simple empty text file, 
**The script is working fine when launched from shell.**

I looked at `var/log/syslog` and found the following entries:

```
Nov  7 07:55:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[6984]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov  7 08:00:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7032]: pam_ecryptfs: Skipping automatic eCryptfs mount
Nov  7 08:00:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7033]: (asarluhi) CMD (/home/asarluhi/Documents/Scripts/monday.sh)
Nov  7 08:00:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7031]: (asarluhi) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Nov  7 08:00:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7038]: pam_ecryptfs: Skipping automatic eCryptfs unmount
Nov  7 08:00:43 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 anacron[6485]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Nov  7 08:00:43 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 anacron[6485]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Nov  7 08:05:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7112]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov  7 08:10:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7141]: pam_ecryptfs: Skipping automatic eCryptfs mount
Nov  7 08:10:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7142]: (asarluhi) CMD (/home/asarluhi/Documents/Scripts/monday.sh)
Nov  7 08:10:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7140]: (asarluhi) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)
Nov  7 08:10:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7147]: pam_ecryptfs: Skipping automatic eCryptfs unmount
Nov  7 08:15:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7206]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
Nov  7 08:17:01 SATELLITE-L50-A-161 CRON[7221]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
...
```

As you can notice, cron jobs start at 8:00 am rather than at 6:00 am as in the crontable. 
The script is launched but nothing is written in `~/Documents/Scripts/monday` 
I read in the [Cron not running scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134521/cron-not-running-scripts) previous askubuntu question that STDERR should end up in the system mail, but there are not directories named after my user name in `/var/mail/`, so I found nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the executable `ruby` is not in `cron`'s path, so you need to use the full path to the executable.

Change your `monday.sh` script from:

```
#!/bin/bash
ruby ~/Documents/Scripts/monday_task.rb >> ~/Documents/Scripts/monday
```

to:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby /home/asarluhi/Documents/Scripts/monday_task.rb >> /home/asarluhi/Documents/Scripts/monday
```

As your `syslog` demonstrates the `monday.sh` script is being run on time so absolute path-names is the only answer. As per OP comment `ruby` also has to be prefixed with absolute path-name.

Comment: I used the full path in monday.sh: cron launched the script but failed again to write to the file. I thought the use of the full path was important in the crontab, not in the script. As for the ruby interpreter, the full path is /home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby but hidden files cannot be executed from shell. Again, when the original script is launched from shell it works.

Comment: Can you try putting `/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby` into your `monday.sh` script and see if cron runs the job correctly?

Comment: It worked. So as you suggested it is necessary to use the full path everywhere. cron can execute hidden files too.

Comment: Wonderful! It's nice to see something working according to plan. I'll update the answer with your full ruby path name.

Comment: The full path name of the ruby interpreter is /home/asarluhi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby

Comment: For root, `~` would expand to `/root`, not `/home/root`. And `/root` definitely exists.

Comment: @muru Thanks. I knew /root existed but thought ~ automatically meant /home/username.... I was about to revise the answer. But super-fast poster Zanna beat me to it. (Thank you Zanna!)